# Django multiple formset initial datas

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a formset and a variable with lists of Queryset. I tried:
views.py

```
Itemformset = Itemform(initial=[
            {'Item': request.session.get('product_ids')}
        ])
```

But it's empty and I know it is because in this variable are more than one value. How can I pass the values in the formset?

Content of request.session.get('product_ids'):

```
['2', '1']
```

model of modelformset:

```
class OrderItems(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Item = models.ForeignKey('Products', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity')
    Price = models.DecimalField('Price', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    OrderNo = models.ForeignKey('Orders', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Itemformset = Itemform(initial=[
            {'Item': product, 'Quantity': 1}
            for product in request.session.get('product_ids')
        ])
```

is the solution